# JSF переход на другую страницу

Tags: java, веб-программирование, eclipse, jsf, primefaces

Начинаю работать с JSF, возникла такая проблема: захотел сделать простенькую форму, в которую записывается текст, а при нажатии кнопки выводится ниже. Код брал с PrimeFaces.org

Код для xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5">
        <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name:" style="font-weight:bold" />
        <p:inputText id="name" value="#{basicView.text}" />
        <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" icon="ui-icon-check" />
        <h:outputText id="display" value="#{basicView.text}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Код бинов

```
    private String text;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
```

Так же есть 2 xhtml файла: логин и welcome. На welcome не попасть, пока не введёшь логин.

Логин

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>#{i18n.loginTitle}</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="loginForm">
        <p:growl id="msg" showDetail="true" life="3000" />
        <p:panel header="#{i18n.auth}" style="width: 360px;margin: 100px auto 0;">
            <h:panelGrid id="loginPanel" columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="#{i18n.login}:" />
                <p:inputText id="username" required="true" value="#{loginBacking.login}"></p:inputText>
                <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                <p:message for="username"></p:message>
                <h:outputText value="#{i18n.password}:" />
                <p:password id="password" required="true" value="#{loginBacking.password}"></p:password>
                <p:message for="password"></p:message>
                <p:spacer></p:spacer>
                <p:commandButton action="#{loginBacking.login}" value="#{i18n.loginBtn}" update="loginForm" ajax="true"></p:commandButton>
                <p:link outcome="pub/registration" value="#{i18n.registration}"></p:link>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Welcome

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>#{i18n.homeTitle}</title>
</h:head>
<h:body bgcolor="white">
    <h:form id="logoutForm">
        <p:toolbar>
            <f:facet name="right">
                <p:commandButton actionListener="#{loginBacking.logout}" value="#{i18n.exit}" ajax="false"></p:commandButton>
            </f:facet>
        </p:toolbar>
    </h:form>
    <p:layout style="min-width:600px;min-height:200px;">
        <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="150" minSize="40"
            maxSize="200">
            Menu
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <h:form id="welForm">
        <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5">
            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name:" style="font-weight:bold" />
            <p:inputText id="name" value="#{homeBacking.text}" />
            <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" icon="ui-icon-check" ajax="true" >
            </p:commandButton>
            <h:outputText id="display" value="#{homeBacking.text}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Welcome бин

```
private String text;

public String getText() {
    return text;
}
public void setText(String text) {
```

Faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>ru</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>resources</base-name>
            <var>i18n</var>
        </resource-bundle>
        <resource-handler>utils.LocalizedResourceHandler</resource-handler>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>hello.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>ui-lightness</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/web_jsf/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

При переходе с логина на welcome, в браузерной строке остаётся login.xhtml. При обновлении опять появляется страница логина. Если забиваю в форму текст и нажимаю кнопку, то текст не выводится. Если меняю параметр `ajax="true"` на `ajax="false"`, то при нажатии на кнопку выбрасывает на страницу логина.
В чём может быть дело?

Comment: Что может помешать попасть сразу на Welcome? Кроме того, похоже, не вставился код loginBacking бина.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно, для того, чтобы преградить неаутентифицированным и/или неавторизованным пользователям путь к какой-либо странице, реализуется фильтр (в соответствии со спецификацией Servlet API, [в вашем случае вот этой](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=154)), который перехватывает обращения по сконфигурированным путям и при необходимости перенаправляет пользователя на `login.xhtml`. В web.xml это может выглядеть так:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LocalAuthFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.webapp.filters.AuthFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LocalAuthFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/web_jsf/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/logout.xhtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Кроме этого, метод в `loginBacking` бине, обрабатывающий нажатие на кнопку логина, должен возвращать `String`: например, `"SUCCESS"` или `"FAIL"`. Это будет Ваш outcome. И для этого "исхода" аутентификации в faces-config.xml нужно написать правила навигации. Например, так:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{loginBacking.login}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>SUCCESS</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/web_jsf/welcome.xhtml</to-view-id>            
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{loginBacking.login}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>FAIL</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/web_jsf/error.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Обратите внимание на элемент `<redirect/>`. Он как раз и означает, что запрос не просто будет передан другому view, но и браузер перейдёт по новому адресу. Соответственно, в адресной строке будет написан тот адрес, на который Вы направили посетителя после логина.

Возможен и другой путь: навигационные правила в `faces-config.xml` указывать необязательно, если в качестве "исхода" Вы возвращаете непосредственно идентификатор view. Тогда для перехода с редиректом необходимо к идентификатору view добавить параметр `?faces-redirect=true`

Comment: верно, у меня переход на страницы происходит путём возвращения welcome и login соответственно, как вы указали во втором варианте. Если я ставлю `welcome?faces-redirect=true`, то со страницы логина я никуда не перехожу, так на ней и остаюсь, хотя происходит проверка пользователя и пароля.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо этого возвращать `/web_jsf/welcome.xhtml?faces-redirect=true` - при такой форме нужен правильный путь к view. По сути, Вы в этом случае возвращаете строку запроса. Мы здесь говорим о значении "outcome" - строки, которую возвращает action-метод.

Comment: Если же Вы используете навигационные правила в faces-config.xml, то см. как это описано в ответе. Разница в том, что в faces-config.xml Вы управляете навигационными правилами централизованно, в некоторых IDE есть даже визуализаторы навигации. А в случае возврата навигационных правил прямо из кода Вы видите их прямо на том месте, где принимаете решение об их выборе.